# Truncate all values in a flat array to n characters

Tags: php, arrays, truncate

How can I limit the character length of all string inside an array?

Like `chunk_split ( $string, 10 );`

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foofoofoofoofoofoofoo",
    "name" => "name34234242224"
);
```

I do not want more than 10 characters in any string.

Comment: Don't add items of more than 10 characters when building the array?  Can you show context of how you are trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $array[$key] = substr($value,0,10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array_map(function($value) {
    return substr($value, 0, 10);
}, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each item in the array, and run `chunk_split()` on it:

```
foreach ($array as $key => value) {
    $array[$key] = chunk_split($value, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop each element with a foreach and get first 10 characters.
this function is static. it means it won't check for new element anymore.
you could create a check method for each new element inserted.

```
foreach ($array as $key => value) {

    $array[$key] = chunk_split($value, 10);

}
```

now, for every element you will insert, call this function for check the length of the string:

```
function newElement($array, $element) {

    array_push($array, substring($element, 10));

    return $array;

}
```